# Installing Postgres custom type - could not access file "...": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, unix, file-permissions

Using postgres11, I'm trying to register the example `Complex` type that comes in the source distribution.

I've built the type without any problems:

```
git clone https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git
cd postgres/src/tutorial
make
```

But when I try to install it, I run into a permission problem:

```
~/p/s/tutorial> psql -U postgres -W 
Password: 
psql (11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c testdata
Password for user postgres: 
You are now connected to database "testdata" as user "postgres".
testdata=# 
testdata=# \i complex.sql
psql:complex.sql:39: NOTICE:  type "complex" is not yet defined
DETAIL:  Creating a shell type definition.
psql:complex.sql:39: ERROR:  could not access file "/home/mnuttall/postgres/src/tutorial/complex": Permission denied
psql:complex.sql:47: ERROR:  type complex does not exist
```

I'm not sure where exactly the permission problem is coming from, as I've changed the permissions for everything in the src/tutorial directory to 777.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your home directory is not accessible to system user `postgres`.

You need to make sure that the permissions of the directories above allow user `postgres` to enter the directory (`r-x`). So possible solution would be to run:

```sh
$ chmod o+rx $HOME
```

If this doesn't help make sure to run the command on every other directory in the path as well.

Comment: face palm! 
Thanks Jakub :)